# Problem with sending DTMF tones from android app over an active call

Tags: android

The DTMF tones are getting generated on my Experia 10 [Android 2.1]. The problem is, I was expecting this kind of behavior :- 
I call a number, and the call is accepted at the other end. Then I run my application, and I generate DTMF tones from the app. and the same tones should be received at the other end of the call. 
But this is not happening. I want to know a way, using which I can send DTMF signals over to the other end through a normal phone call. Is there a way to intercept an outgoing call and generate DTMF in between that call ? Please help ! Got stuck with this !
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know a way, using which I can send DTMF signals over to the other end through a normal phone call.

Android applications have no access to the in-call audio stream. You can fake a it a bit in speakerphone mode.

> Is there a way to intercept an outgoing call and generate DTMF in between that call ?

No.

Comment: Then can we give output of the speaker to the MIC of the phone by any means ?